# sql server - making a result vertical to horizontal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, database-administration

```
SELECT
    FirstName + '_count' AS firstName,
    COUNT(distinct FirstName) AS Count1
FROM
    test1(nolock)
GROUP BY
    FirstName
```

Result is coming up as:

```
firstName                                                Count1
-------------------------------------------------------- -----------
Bruce_count                                              1
Haley_count                                              1
Madeline_count                                           1
Marshall_count                                           1
Sophia_count                                             1

(5 row(s) affected)
```

I need it to be

```
firstName                                                Count1
-------------------------------------------------------- -----------
Bruce_count  Haley_count     Madeline_count    Marshall_count    Sophia_count                                
1  1  1  1  1 1 <br/>
(5 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: How do you want the result?? Each `firstName` as a column?

Comment: You do this either using `pivot` or conditional aggregation.

Comment: [Pivot] (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) is what you are looking for

Comment: HI Ullaas yes , each first name to be a column